# Specifying buffer size in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

How do I specify buffer size in sqlserver? I want to increase the buffer size so that I can see a performance gains.

I'm not sure how to get the default value and how to increase it..

I see these types of values specified as the buffer size ---1<<24 & at 2**24---

Answer (score 1):

You can't really control the buffer pool directly in SQL Server.  You can only increase the min and max memory settings which will allow SQL to dynamically increase or decrease the amount of memory in the buffer pool.